# Find all $n$ for which $10\mid(n-1)!+1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Here is what I did:
From that question it implies that

$10\not\mid(n-1)!$.

Now $n$ has to be $\lt 5$. Otherwise the above condition will not be true. We can easily check for $1,2,3,4$ and see that no value satisfy the given condition. My textbook says that this proof is used to prove that.

> There are infinite $n$ such that $10\mid\phi(n)$ .

Now I am completely lost. I can't see how the above result is related to this. Any suggestions ( Even if the method doesn't rely on derived result,I am fine with it as long as it is elementary)

Comment: what is $phi(n)$ ? why does that contradict what you proved?

Comment: The title is actually very misleading because it suggests that there is a solution for $n$, but apparently there isn't. Obviously, if $(n-1)!$ is divisible by 10, $(n-1)!+1$ is not, because the +1 is a remainder. For lower n up till 5 it's just checking.

Comment: Is the $phi(n)$ you're referring to the [Euler totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)?

Comment: Can you tell which *book* you are using ?

Comment: @John Omielan Yes

Comment: I cannot understand how it is possible to use that $\,10\not\mid(n-1)!+1\,$ for any $\,n\in\Bbb N\,$ in order to prove that there are infinitely many $n$ such that $\,10\mid\phi(n)\,.\;$ Please, could someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :** There are infinite primes of the form $10n+1$.

Do you recall the formula for $\phi(p)$ when $p$ is prime $?$

---

Even simpler , we don't even need to know that there are infinite primes of the form $10n+1 . $ Just take one such number , for eg. $11$ and multiply it with any prime number . The resultant number would always be  $10\mid\phi(n)$ and since there are infinite primes , we can construct infinite numbers.

Comment: Or just take the powers of $11$.

Comment: I cannot understand how it is possible to use that $\,10\not\mid(n-1)!+1\,$ for any $\,n\in\Bbb N\,$ in order to prove that there are infinitely many $n$ such that $\,10\mid\phi(n)\,.\;$ Please, could you explain it to me?

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in the body:

> There are infinite $n$ such that $10\mid\phi(n)$ .

Indeed, take $n=5^k$ with $k\ge 2$. Then $\phi(n)=5^{k-1}\cdot 4$, which is a multiple of $20$.

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A066500

Comment: I cannot understand how it is possible to use that $\,10\not\mid(n-1)!+1\,$ for any $\,n\in\Bbb N\,$ in order to prove that there are infinitely many $n$ such that $\,10\mid\phi(n)\,.\;$ Please, could you explain it to me?